# How to get the index of int array when using linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i want to create a Dropdownlist with specific numbers in MVC

So in my model i have a property :

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Quantities { get; set; }
```

In my controller i instantiate my model :

```
Quantities = from s in numbers
             select new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString()}
```

numbers is a int array with 10 numbers in it.

This code works but the problem is i cant get the value(index) of the array from 's'.

Does anyone know how i can get this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with LINQ expressions. You could use the following:

```
Quantities = numbers.Select((s, index) => new SelectListItem 
{ 
    Value = index.ToString(), 
    Text = s.ToString()
);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly indeed. I dont realy understand it though, the arguments for .select(Func<int, TResult>selector) for example... Its nice when having working code but more fun if you understand it aswell :)

Comment: @wartodust, there are 2 arguments that the anonymous method takes: the first is the current element and the second is an integer representing the index.

Comment: Wow. This is a well hidden LINQ feature !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method syntax instead of the query syntax:

`var quantities = numbers.Select((x,i) => {...});`